# How convert a number in letter in smarty?

Tags: smarty

I want to put letters instead of numbers.For example, if I have the following statement:

```
{for $node=1 to {$nr_nods}}
 {$nod}<br>
{/for}
```

where {$nr_nods}=3, will show

```
   1
   2
   3
```

,but Y want display

```
   A
   B
   C
```

how make this?

Answer (score 1):

In php, assign an array to the template with the equivalences:

```
$smarty->assign('nums'=>array(1=>'A',2=>'B',3=>'C'));
```

and then just output the values by key:

```
{$nums.$nod}
```